# SQL Database, ERD, crows foot notation,

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I have an ERD diagram where I have the crows foot on the customer going into a dotted line then  straight line to membership. Does this mean that Members must be customers and customers may hold a membership? 
regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood correctly.
Do you have something like

Customer >- - - - - ----Membership

correct?

If that's the case it means that a membership can be owned by multiple customers, that it's compulsory for a customer to have a membership (mandatory relationship - if it were optional you'd have a 0 at the membership table line), and the dotted line it means that it's a non-identifying one (i.e: the foreign key is not part of the members primary key - or similarly that a customer is not identified by its membership)

Comment: if i have customer>-------  - - - - - -  - Membership, does that mean customers may have a membership but membership doesn't not have to be owneed by customers?

Comment: This is one to many relationship. One membership can have many customers or members. For ex., Membership_1 can have customer_a, cust_b, cust_c etc... as members. All these customers are members of the Membership_1. The membership_id is common for these customers.

Comment: In that case you would have Customer>- - - - - ----0-Membership

Answer (score 0):

Some people use dashed lines to indicate that a relationship is purely *associative* as opposed to solid lines being for relationships that are *identifying*.

There are lots of different graphical conventions used for ERDs.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow%27s_foot_notation#Crow.27s_Foot) for several examples.  This means that you can't be absolutely sure what was intended without asking the person who created the diagram.  However, you can take a pretty good guess based on convention and what makes logical sense.

It makes sense that a relationship between customers and membership would be associative rather than identifying.